# Coding Distributions as a Convex Constraint

Tags: probability-distributions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In convex optimization, how can we impose a constraint that a variable has certain distribution?
e.g. elements of vector $v$ have power law distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that in general such a constraint cannot be guaranteed to preserve convexity. For example, any non-continuous distribution or any continuous distribution which has a probability zero mid-region will very likely break convexity.

Comment: I can't see why.

Comment: @user25004 because these are non-convex constraints. Convexity requires that any point between 2 feasible solutions to also be a feasible solution. For example consider a distribution that forces the solution to be integer. Then take two feasible solutions (integers) - a point in between them may not be integer and will violate the convexity. Restriction to integers is also known as Integer Programming and is NP-hard.